# What input of input stream will cause IOException?

Tags: java, unit-testing, ioexception, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I am trying to create an IOException for a test case. But finding it difficult to find the right input to cause the exception

```
private static JsonNode getJsonNode(final HttpBlobOutput SomeBlob) throws IOException {

return com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.reader().readTree(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                SomeBlob.getByteBufferData().array()));
```

What kind of bytebufferdata input to the SomeBlob will create an IOException?

ie. What input will cause an IOException in readTree() and readValue() ObjectMapper methods?

Answer (score 0):

The `IOException`, if it occurs, will come from the `InputStream`'s Read methods.

The Documentation for the [Read methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) indicates that `IOException` will be thrown

> If the first byte cannot be read for any reason other than the end of the file, if the input stream has been closed, or if some other I/O error occurs.

The [Documentation for IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) says:

> This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations.

It also lists several subclasses that characterize the nature of such errors.  For example: `ClosedChannelException`, `FileNotFoundException`, etc.

Comment: Is there a specific input that can cause this issue?
My question is what value of SomeBlob will throw the IOException

Comment: Based on the documentation I've provided, I'm not sure there is one.